# accessing master page contents webform vs MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I know you can access master page element from content pages in webform world by adding a reference then calling Page.Master.

How can same be done in MVC 3.0 World?

Comment: ASPX or Razor? What are you trying to access?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? That should not be necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access elements in the layout from the view - this is MVC and not Web Forms.

There are no controls like in web forms which you can reference and manipulate.

If you want to change anything in the layout from within the view:

- Use `ViewBag` (as others here suggested) to pass values up to the layout (to display them, use them for conditions, pass them to `RenderAction` calls or to partial views, ...). The same can be done by using a common `BaseViewModel` and strongly typing the layout.
- Define a `Rendersection` in your layout and place a `section` attribute in your view - whatever you put in the section will be rendered in the layout.

Answer (score 1):

The rendering system is different between two.

Razor views renders from child to parent which means your Layout page will be rendered lastly.

For example, the below part is from you Layout page:

```
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
```

And you can determine what title will be from your View like below:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Poo";
}
```

So this is a prof of rendering order.

Comment: my question is about accessing master page element from content. Not sure what it has to do with question. Kindly elaborate.

Comment: @palmsnow read the answer again, you will see it is related to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be doing this. 
The 'master' page is rendered in REVERSE order than is done in web forms, so the content isn't there yet.
Why are you trying to access it, maybe we have a better solution for you?

EDIT: Sorry tugberk, I see mine is basically what you said but maybe to a point the op gets here ha : )

Comment: yep, yours is hitting the topic :)